# Fantasy book series about Gods of Order and Chaos

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember reading a long time ago about a book series where the Gods of Chaos ruled the world, and the followers of the Gods of Order were heretics and secret.

Over the course of the book, or books, the Gods of Order are restored, and the Chaos gods were banished. Then heretics start worshipping the Chaos gods to bring them back. They basically alternate ruling the world, back and forth. There are Chaos Storms, and Chaos horses, and other fantasy tropes.

Any ideas? For the life of me, I can't remember the name or author. I do remember the Chaos Gods, there is a blonde haired one, and a dark, serious one, if that helps.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you clarify roughly which years or decade you read these books in? Also, can you recall any details about the main character/s, or any of the covers? If so, please [edit] them into your question.

Answer (score 8):

That sounds like the [*Time Master*](http://www.louisecooper.com/fiction/tm_books_tm.html) series by Louise Cooper.  The books are:

1. The Initiate
2. The Outcast
3. The Master

Long ago, the 7 Chaos gods were banished by the 7 gods of Order and the world is ruled by Order.  But the Chaos gods are trying to return.  Chaos re-arising in the land is heralded by Chaos storms.  Chaotic steeds are mentioned as having been used by the old servants of the chaos gods.  They only show up in the very beginning of the first book, where the victory of the gods of Order is shown.

Yandros is one of the Chaos gods.  He is described as having gold hair:

> The Great Lord of Chaos had taken human form. Gold hair, wild and unkempt, rippled over his shoulders

The other god:

> The main character, Tarod, has black hair and is also a god of Chaos.

There are also Warps, which turn out to be chaos made manifest. These could be the Chaos Storms you remember.

From the author's website:

> The seven gods of Order had ruled unchallenged for centuries, served
> by the adepts of the Circle in their bleak northern castle on the Star
> Peninsula. But for Tarod—the most enigmatic and formidable sorcerer in
> the Circle’s ranks—a darker affinity had begun to call. Threatening
> his beliefs, even his sanity, it rose unbidden from beyond time; an
> ancient and deadly adversary that could plunge the world into madness
> and chaos—and whose power might rival that of the gods themselves.
>
> And though Tarod’s mind and heart were pledged to Order, his soul was
> another matter...

Comment: That is probably it, although some details don't quite match. I don't recall any Chaos Storms or Chaos Horses. And the order is different: it starts out with Order ruling and ends up with Chaos.

Comment: @Moriarty The Chaos storms were called Warp or Warp storms, I think.  The first chapter of the first book was set at the time of chaos ruling.

Comment: LAK, I just checked my copy and you re correct, there are Warps which are chaos made manifest.  There's a brief prolog where Chaos ruled but the rest of the three volumes has Order in charge. So I wonder if the asker simply got the roles reversed or whether he was thinking of the prequel trilogy which had Chaos in charge, overturned by Order at the end?

Comment: I've edited the answer to add a bit about Warps.

Comment: @Moriarty Thanks for the edit.  I think I misread that the statement books tell about Chaos overthrowing order.   Either way, I suspect the answer is right.  Hopefully the querent will come back and confirm.  I haven't read the other series beyond the original 3 books  (only because I didn't know about them - I'll rectify that soon)

Answer (score 1):

Could it be ***[The Saga of Recluce](https://www.goodreads.com/series/41825-the-saga-of-recluce)*** by L. E. Modesitt Jr.?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Saga_of_Recluce):

> *The Saga of Recluce* is a series of fantasy novels written by L. E. Modesitt Jr. The initial novel in the series, *The Magic of Recluce* (from which the series derives its name), was published in 1991. The series is still in publication with the latest, *Fairhaven Rising*, published in February 2021. In 2015 Modesitt stated that the then 20 novels in the *Recluce* series had sold nearly three million copies.
>
> The 20 books of the series describe the changing, often confrontational, relationship between the descendants of two technologically advanced cultures, representatives of whom have been marooned on a sparsely inhabited world and regressed to the level of the existing inhabitants' primitive technology. Themes of gender stereotyping, sexism, ageism, racism, ethics, economics, environmentalism and politics are explored in the course of the series, which examines the world through the eyes of its protagonists.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to explain why you think this might be the correct series, i.e. the ways in which it matches the one described in the question.